# Log4j2: unable to set MDC keys using Servlet Context Listener

Tags: web-applications, log4j2, mdc

I'm trying to set the hostname as a MDC variable using a Servlet Context Listener. The MDC variable gets available only in the listener itself, but it disappears if i try to log from other servlets.

Here my listener code:

```
public class MdcServletListener implements ServletContextListener {

    /** logger. */
    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(MdcServletListener.class);

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see javax.servlet.ServletContextListener#contextDestroyed(javax.servlet.
     * ServletContextEvent)
     */
    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sContext) {

    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see
     * javax.servlet.ServletContextListener#contextInitialized(javax.servlet
     * .ServletContextEvent)
     */
    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sContext) {
        try {
            ThreadContext.put("LISTENER", "TEST");
            logger.info("Inizializzazione variabili mdc completata");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Inizializzazione variabili mdc fallita", e);
        }

    }

}
```

Here my web.xml:

```
<listener>
        <listener-class>org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>MdcServletListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>log4jServletFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>log4jServletFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Any suggestion?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MDC configuration holds client specific or request specific data and  is basically done per thread/client. In other words since each client request for a servlet is handled by a separate thread by the container; the configuration should rather go in a filter for that servlet rather than in the ServletContextListener(Your `MdcServletListener` class). The ServletContextListener that you extend is per webapp and does not hold individual request data MDC is intended for.

Would suggest putting this line 
`ThreadContext.put("LISTENER", "TEST");` in your own servlet filter.

And then in your log4j.properties; you can access the above variable that you set using:-
`%X{LISTENER}%n`.

For example your appender configuration in your log4j.properties will change as below:-
`log4j.appender.yourAppender.layout.ConversionPattern = %-4r [%t] %5p %c %x - %m - %X{LISTENER}%n`

In the above example config notice the `%X{LISTENER}%n` added in the end to access the MDC specific data that you set.